# mssql мульти поле как правильно хранить и делать выборку

Tags: sql-server

Требуется хранить в одном поле несколько выбранных параметров. Есть набор кодов, например упростим, до, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666 и тд. 
Знаю, правильнее делать отдельную таблицу с ID и именем, и потом еще одну таблицу со связью этих таблиц... Вобщем не хочу заморачиваться так глобально, т.к. параметров будет не много... Но самих записей с этими параметрами может быть довольно много, тоесть возможна следующая запись:

```
3333
1111,3333
2222,3333
2222
2222
1111
```

Но нужно учесть, чтобы можно было делать выборку, типа

```
SELECT... WHERE LIKE '%3333%'
```

Скажите как правильно хранить это в mssql и делать выборку WHERE

я знаю LIKE есть у MYsql, хотелось бы узнать как правильно для MSSQL и чтобы все это быстро работало, надо ли индекс делать и какой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не будет работать быстро, и никаких способов заставить `LIKE '%что-что%'` работать быстро нет.

Индексы в SQL Server позволяют две вещи:

- Быструю выборку по точному значению
- Быструю выборку по диапазону

Применительно к LIKE это означает что быстрый поиск (INDEX SEEK) по индексу будет работать только для выражений вида `LIKE 'начало%`. Для них можно определить первый элемент в диапазоне (`начало`) и последний (то, что уже не попадает под `начало%`).

`LIKE '%что-что%'` будет приводить к INDEX SCAN - перебору всех значений в индексе.

Если у вас предсказуемое количество значений (не больше 5, например) - сделайте 5-ю колонками, будет работать быстрее.